# Can Yarn dynamically allocate resources to Flink?

Tags: configuration, hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

I am new to Flink on Yarn deployment. 
As far as I know, Flink always reserves the resources (CPUs, RAM) to run on Yarn. And, a Flink platform is considered as a Yarn application.

However, is there any way to configure in such a way that allows Yarn to dynamically allocate resources to Flink?

Answer (score 4):

At the moment there is no such way. However, we already the bits and pieces in place to implement a dynamic resource allocation. See the `YarnFlinkResourceManager` for more information.

### Update

With Flink `1.5.0`, full resource elasticity was added. This means that Flink now dynamically allocates new containers if it needs more slots to execute a job.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.

Comment: Does anything need to be configured for dynamic allocation or is it enabled by default?

Comment: It is enabled by default.